# Why do I lose responsiveness when I add my own css on a bootstrap card

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsiveness

When I add my own Styling on a bootstrap card or any bootstrap component I lose responsiveness. What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: It would be good if you could write here your code or in codepen, so we can see and understand better your question.

Comment: use jsfiddle or Stackoverflow snippet to demonstrate the problem